# Parse.com - I get duplicated push notifications after releasing my application

Tags: android, push-notification, duplicates, parse-platform

Finally after a lot of hassle I released my first Android application after migrating from C# to Java :-)

But now I get duplicated notifications on devices where I've debugged my application before finishing coding.
All other users who installed my application after its release get the push notifications properly without any duplication or any kind of problem.

"After googling & searching I found out that this problem only exists on older Parse.com SDK, but it's weird since I'm using the latest one!"

I've been wondering about two things:

1. Will other users face the same problem after I release an update? ( Version code will be updated - And I'm not using any store, I maintain the updates on a private server & got my own code to do the update process ).
2. How can I solve this problem? I was thinking about creating a new application entry on my Parse.com account for every single new update ( If I'm sure that there isn't any solution ).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MayurRaval Unfortunately not yet, but updating the application ( increasing version code ) solves the problem if no user reinstalls the application. [ Which cannot be guaranteed! ]. Still waiting for an answer :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive testing & checking ..

I found a proper solution, may be good for some, but a lot will not like it.

It's a bug in Parse's SDK itself as I guess, when you delete the application from a device, it won't delete its record from the database. So, when the app is installed again, the same device will have two different records. So it gets 2 duplicates ..  The number grows as much as you uninstall/install!

My solution is to increase the **version code** and change the version, so it'll be considered as a new application by Parse with new records!